# Chrome Extension - permissions for executing code on new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have following code for opening new tab with defined URL and then execute some piece of code on it:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
        'url': 'https://myownServer.com',
        'selected': false
    }, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            'file': 'myCode.js'
        });
    });
```

The tab openes, but when it comes to execute the file (myCode.js), it log to console this error:

```
Uncaught Error: You do not have permission to use 'tabs.executeScript'.
Be sure to declare in your manifest what permissions you need.
```

I have not found any permission like this (except 'tabs', which i'm already having in my manifest.json). What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare host permissions that would allow you to inject content scripts on qualified domains:

```
"permissions": [
  "tabs", "https://myownServer.com/*"
],
```

more about it [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html#pi) and [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/xhr.html#requesting-permission).

Comment: Actually the last star was missing... :-)